# No activity showing for Tor exit relay

Tags: exit-relays

Ive been testing a run of a tor exit relay on a vps which has been active for a few hours however, when using nyx to show traffic stats it shows little to no usage.

Ive also tried searching for my relay on torstatus but no results are shown for the ip.

when running `/usr/sbin/tor --verify-config` it shows the configuration was valid and that its running as an exit node.

I have also ensured that the default accept out and forward policy is enabled. ports 9001 tcp & 80 tcp are also accessible from the outside, verified through a qucik nmap scan.

the traffic for both upload nor download has gone above 1 -2KB

[image]

How long do I have to wait to see any activity on my relay? and is there anything im missing?

Answer (score 1):

So ive been looking into the lifecycle of a tor realy and this seems to behave as you would expect. https://blog.torproject.org/lifecycle-new-relay